# Error during WebSocket handshake (Unexpected response code: 400)

Tags: java, spring, websocket, apache2.4, sockjs

My code perfectly working in localhost but when I put my application to sever this error happens.

> WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://url.com/webSocket/193/uj4s3xue/websocket' failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
>
> sockjs.min.js:2 POST
>   https://url.com/webSocket/193/e1vwalij/xhr_streaming?t=1495418202369
>   403 (Forbidden)

Js code :

```
   function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS('/webSocket');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
            stompClient.debug = null;
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages/' + vm.id, function (greeting) {
                refreshMessages(JSON.parse(greeting.body));
            });
        });
    }
```

Java code :

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.ChannelRegistration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/webSocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Bean
    public PresenceChannelInterceptor presenceChannelInterceptor() {
        return new PresenceChannelInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.setInterceptors(presenceChannelInterceptor());
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.taskExecutor().corePoolSize(8);
        registration.setInterceptors(presenceChannelInterceptor());
    }
}
```

In spring sever following exception happens :

> 2017-05-27 11:14:57.101 ERROR 51230 --- [ XNIO-2 task-11]
>   o.s.w.s.s.s.DefaultHandshakeHandler      : Handshake failed due to
>   invalid Upgrade header: null
>
> 2017-05-27 11:16:10.020 ERROR 51230 --- [MessageBroker-1]
>   o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred
>   in scheduled task.
>
> org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException:
>   Failed to write SockJsFrame content='h'; nested exception is
>   java.io.IOException: Broken pipe  at
>   org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.writeFrame(AbstractSockJsSession.java:339)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.sendHeartbeat(AbstractSockJsSession.java:255)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession$HeartbeatTask.run(AbstractSockJsSession.java:451)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Broken pipe  at
>   sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504)    at
>   org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.write(NioSocketConduit.java:161)    at
>   io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:645)
>     at
>   io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.doWrite(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:163)
>     at
>   io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.write(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:127)
>     at
>   org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:150)
>     at
>   io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.write(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:240)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.write(HttpServerExchange.java:2049)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:570)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.flushInternal(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:485)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.flush(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:472)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.flushBuffer(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:461)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:215)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:215)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:159)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:215)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.flush(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.writeFrameInternal(AbstractHttpSockJsSession.java:350)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.writeFrame(AbstractSockJsSession.java:322)
>     ... 10 common frames omitted

Sever is apache2 web sever. How do I fix this issue?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slove this problem by activating ws_tunnel with

> sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel

and making  RewriteEngine On apache `000-default-le-ssl.conf`  file located in

> /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf

```
  RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /webSocket(.*)           ws://127.0.0.1:8080/webSocket/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: This work for me, just need to change ws:// to wss:// since I am connecting to https protocol.